# Message dialog user's choice Metro app - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Each time the user launches the app, the app asks the user to select "First" or "Second".
If the user's choice is "First" then the message "TEST 1" shows up or if the user's choice is "Second" the message is "TEST 2".

No matter what I select the message is always "TEST 1".

What is wrong with my code?

How can I get it to work?

```
var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("Choose first or second.", "Test");

// Add commands and set their command handlers
msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("First", commandInvokedHandler));

msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Second", commandInvokedHandler));

// Set the command that will be invoked by default
msg.defaultCommandIndex = 1;

// Set the command to be invoked when escape is pressed
msg.cancelCommandIndex = 1;

// Show the message dialog
msg.showAsync();

if (msg = 1) {
  // First Choice
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  applyButton.addEventListener("click", buttonFirst, false);
} else {
  // Second Choice
  var button = document.getElementById("button");
  applyButton.addEventListener("click", buttonSecond, false);
}

function buttonFirst(eventInfo) {
  var greetingString = "TEST 1";
  document.getElementById("first").innerText = greetingString;
}

function buttonSecond(eventInfo) {
  var greetingString = "TEST 2";
  document.getElementById("second").innerText = greetingString;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(msg =  1) {` should be `if(msg == 1) {` otherwise you're setting it to 1 then checking it.

**EDIT:**

On closer inspection,, there's bigger problems here. Why add eventListeners separately? [The spec for the UICommand class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/BR242166) states that the second parameter is the callback. So instead of the way you're creating your buttons, why not do:

```
msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("First", buttonFirst));

msg.commands.append(new Windows.UI.Popups.UICommand("Second", buttonSecond));
```

Comment: Please see my edit. Not sure if that'll fix it, but I have a feeling it might help

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. What I did is I replaced `commandInvokedHandler` with `buttonFirst` and `buttonSecond` and I also removed `if else` from the event handlers. I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Comment: I assume you do have the two elements with ID's `first` and `second`?

Comment: Yes their ID's are `first` and `second`.

Comment: In which case I'm out of ideas. Sorry